# change image src with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code

```
function playPause(){
    movie = document.getElementById('movieEMBED');
    icon = document.getElementById('playPauseIcon');
    var isPlaying;
    isPlaying = movie.GetRate();
    if (!isPlaying){
        movie.Play();
        icon.setAttribute('src', "images/pausebutton.png");
    }
    else {
        movie.Stop();
        icon.setAttribute('src', "images/playbutton.png");
    }
}
```

in the html:

```
<input type="image" id="playPauseIcon" src="images/playbutton.png" width=30px onClick='playPause()'></input>
```

Any ideas as to why the picture does not switch between the pause and play button when I click the button?

Comment: nevermind, this code works, i just had pausebutton.png mistyped as pausebotton.png in my images folder :(

Comment: Why use `icon.setAttribute('src', "images/pausebutton.png");` when `icon.src = "images/pausebutton.png";` is more compact and seems in tune with the language (you're just setting a property value).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's because your movie is playing.  The `else` of the if block sets the src to the same value:

```
if (!isPlaying){
    movie.Play();
    icon.setAttribute('src', "images/pausebutton.png");
}
else {
    movie.Stop();
    icon.setAttribute('src', "images/playbutton.png"); // <---- no change
}
```

---

Just to be sure that your code is right, which it appears to be, I would change the function to this:

```
function playPause(){
    var icon = document.getElementById('playPauseIcon');
    icon.setAttribute('src', "images/pausebutton.png");
}
```

and then slowly add in your movie code

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your code is fine. Are you sure movie.GetRate() returns different values and you're passing by both paths of the 'if' correctly? I would think movie.GetRate() is returning always the same value so you never set the src attribute to a different image.